# In ListReceivedByAddress, what is the meaning of Confirmations if the address is reused?

Tags: development, json-rpc, confirmations, api

The API `ListReceivedByAddress` allows me to view a list a sum* of all the transactions that an address has received.   This returns an array listing the sum of what was sent.

- If the address is reused for more than one transaction, what is the expected value of "confirmations"?
- Is the value of confirmations the Max, Min, or Average?
- Should there be an entry listing how many transactions were sent to that address?

---

*Footnote I'm not entirely sure that the ListReceivedByAddress actually returns a sum of all transactions to that address.  I assume it's possible that the value could be the first, last,or sum of all transactions to an address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the address is reused for more than one transaction, what is the expected value of "confirmations"?

Quote from [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list):

```
"confirmations" : number of confirmations of the most recent transaction included
```

Also, I think you might want to change the value of `minconf` that you pass to `listrecievedbyaddress` if you're concerned about knowing how many confirmations a transaction has.

> Should there be an entry listing how many transactions were sent to that address?

Why would you use that though?